# How to query objects by attribute in IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, database-cursor

I have an IndexedDB object store, which stores user-objects of the following structure:

```
{ id: 1, name: "Peter", role: "admin", password: "someHash"}
```

The object store is created as follows:

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
    var db = request.result;
    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("users", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });

    objectStore.createIndex("uniqueNameIndex", "name", { unique: true  });
    objectStore.createIndex("roleIndex",       "role", { unique: false });
};
```

I know how to retrieve an object by its key (the id), and I am also able to iterate over all objects using a cursor. [Here's a working demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbxxRw)

What I wanna do now is to get all users who have a specific role - eg. retrieve all admins, without iterating the whole object store.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function forEachAdmin(db, callback) {
  var ROLE_ADMIN = 'admin';
  var tx = db.transaction('users');
  var store = tx.objectStore('users');
  var index = store.index('roleIndex');
  var range = IDBKeyRange.only(ROLE_ADMIN);
  var request = index.openCursor(range);
  request.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = this.result;
    if(cursor) {
      var adminUser = cursor.value;
      callback(adminUser);
      cursor.continue();
    } else {
      // No admins found or all admins iterated
    }
  };
}

function handleAdmin(user) {
  console.log('Doing something with admin user %o', user);
}

var request = indexedDB.open('dbname');
request.onsuccess = function() {
  var db = this.result;
  forEachAdmin(db, handleAdmin);
};
```